# Content not showing

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a website and I was able to get this page working before. I am not sure when it happened but this specific page only shows a part of the content on the website. I tried the plugins and everything and nothing seemed to help. I did switch themes and that worked but I don't get why it would not work on this specific page. I copied code from another page and it is the same problem. I have deleted the page and created a new one and it is still the same problem even with working code from another page.

I only have a problem with this one specific page.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening.

I have deactivated plugins and reactivated them
I tried switching themes which worked but it's not the theme I need.
I took working code pages and copied them into this page and it won't work.
I have deleted the page and created a new one.

Comment: You may want to update with the code for that page template. I assume you have a template file and it is assigned to that page

Comment: So it's something funky with the link. I redid the page and named it something completely different. It worked. So Ichanged it to the original link and it messed up again. Not sure why. It's not crucial so I will just leave it as a different name